# Pagination in Firebase when sorting on key

Tags: pagination, firebase-realtime-database

**Solutions in ANY language will be highly appreciated.**

I have a collection of messages like so:

```
"group_messages": {
    "-FirebaseID": {
        "group": "-FirebaseID"
        "timestamp": ...
    }
}
```

When I want to obtain messages using Firebase, it's quite simple I just do this:

```
firebase.database().ref('/group_messages").orderByChild("group").equalTo(...).on(...)
```

However, lets say I just want the last 50 messages, then I would have to orderByChild("timestamp") however Firebase does not allow you to run two .orderBy queries, which results in having to download all of the messages from the database.

So how would I need to structure my data so I can paginate based on timestamp and keep my messages seperate from the `groups/` path, as if the messages are a child of the `group` then they will all be loaded with the group onto the client.

I would like to be able to load messages 1-50 in a group, then once the user scrolls far enough, load message 51-100. However every Firebase query I can think of involves pulling all of the data to the client upfront.

> NOTE: I do not want to do client-side pagination. The reason we need
>   pagination is because we have too many messages and it's slowing down
>   our application waiting on them to all be loaded.